# How to select rows with NaN in particular column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataframe, how to select only those rows that have "Col2" equal to `NaN`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(3), [0, np.NaN, 0], [0, 0, np.NaN], range(3), range(3)], columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"])
```

which looks like:

```
   0   1   2
0  0   1   2
1  0 NaN   0
2  0   0 NaN
3  0   1   2
4  0   1   2
```

The result should be this one:

```
   0   1   2
1  0 NaN   0
```

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df[df['Col2'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Alternatively `df.loc[df['Col2'].isnull()]` if .loc is your kind of thing

Comment: Q: How to negate thi, i.e. where data in column "is not null"? A: by using the `.notnull()` operator.

Comment: How to select rows of a df, when multiple columns are null? not just any one, but only when a set of columns are null.

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala try this: `df[df['Col1'].isnull() & df['Col2'].isnull()]`

Answer (score 16):

@qbzenker provided the [most idiomatic method IMO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43831589/5741205)

Here are a few alternatives:

```
In [28]: df.query('Col2 != Col2') # Using the fact that: np.nan != np.nan
Out[28]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     0   NaN   0.0

In [29]: df[np.isnan(df.Col2)]
Out[29]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3
1     0   NaN   0.0
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to select rows with at least one NaN value, then you could use `isna` + `any` on `axis=1`:

```
df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

If you want to select rows with a certain number of NaN values, then you could use `isna` + `sum` on `axis=1` + `gt`. For example, the following will fetch rows with at least 2 NaN values:

```
df[df.isna().sum(axis=1)>1]
```

If you want to limit the check to specific columns, you could select them first, then check:

```
df[df[['Col1', 'Col2']].isna().any(axis=1)]
```

If you want to select rows with all NaN values, you could use `isna` + `all` on `axis=1`:

```
df[df.isna().all(axis=1)]
```

If you want to select rows with no NaN values, you could `notna` + `all` on `axis=1`:

```
df[df.notna().all(axis=1)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
df[df['Col1'].notna() & df['Col2'].notna() & df['Col3'].notna()]
```

which could become tedious if there are many columns. Instead, you could use `functools.reduce` to chain `&` operators:

```
import functools, operator
df[functools.reduce(operator.and_, (df[i].notna() for i in df.columns))]
```

or `numpy.logical_and.reduce`:

```
import numpy as np
df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[i].notna() for i in df.columns])]
```

---

If you're looking for filter the rows where there is no NaN in some column using `query`, you could do so by using `engine='python'` parameter:

```
df.query('Col2.notna()', engine='python')
```

or use the fact that `NaN!=NaN` like [@MaxU - stop WAR against UA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43831705/17521785)

```
df.query('Col2==Col2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you may wish to consider this alternative option as well:

```
df[df["Col2"].isna()]
```